# NiFi: QueryElasticSearchHttp: Matching Objects with Expression Language?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

I have a NiFi flow where I bring in some data through an API, which I easily route into ElasticSearch.

I have a second flow where I need to use the processor `QueryElasticSearchHttp`. Within that processor, I have a JSON query:

```
{
    "query" : { 
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                { "match" : { "Example1" : ${Example1} } },
                { "match" : { "ExampleCode" : ${ExampleCode} } }
            ]
        }
    }       
}
```

I am trying to match the object `Example1` and `ExampleCode` and return the whole column. I've tried to inject expression language into the query. Does not work, and I cannot find an example of how to match on an entire object.

I have tried to put quotation marks like so: `"${}"`.

I get the error:

```
ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] ...from Elasticsearch due to 
Elasticsearch returned code 400 with message Bad Request, transferring 
flow file to failure: 
org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.UnretryableException: 
Elasticsearch returned code 400 with message Bad Request
```

The Attributes are also correctly routed, and appear where they need to appear.

What is the correct way to format this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `JsonQueryElasticsearch` processor. A demo flow shown below:

**Overall Flow**
[image: Overall flow]

**Start Step**
[image: Start Step]

**Query ES Step**
[image: Query ES Step]

**The JSON query**
[image: The JSON query]

**Store Result Step**
[image]

**The Controller Service**
[image: The Controller Service]

**Output of Run:**

```
$ cd /var/so_out
$ cat 17973351988502 | python -m json.tool
[
    {
        "_id": "o002",
        "_index": "office",
        "_score": 0.26742277,
        "_source": {
            "description": "Shows and events",
            "name": "Tom",
            "title": "Marketing Manager"
        },
        "_type": "doc"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! My question really revolves around on how to query an entire object, or how to append an object/column. In this case, the `${}` does not return anything

Comment: Can you please provide two things? (1) The indexed document in Elasticsearch (2) The query that runs directly against Elasticsearch and returns the result.